# Connect to gitlab production postgresql database with psycopg2?

Tags: python, postgresql, gitlab, psycopg2

I am trying to connect to GitLab production (installed with omnibus package) postgresql database with psycopg2.

My configuration is like below:

```
onn = psycopg2.connect(database="gitlabhq_production", user="gitlab-psql", host="/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql", port="5432")
```

It gives the following error:

```
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "gitlab-psql"
```

I can connect to the postgresql server on command line with:

```
sudo -u gitlab-psql -i bash /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql --port 5432 -h /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql -d gitlabhq_production
```

Does anyone know what will be the correct parameters to pass into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peer authentication works by checking the user the process is running as. In your command line example you switch to `gitlab-psql` using `sudo`.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Assign a password to the `gitlab-psql` postgres user (*not* the system user!) and use that to connect via python. Setting the password is just another query you need to run as a superuser like so:

   ```
   sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER gitlab-psql WITH PASSWORD 'ReplaceThisWithYourLongAndSecurePassword';"
   ```
2. Run your python script as `gitlab-psql` like so:

   ```
   sudo -u gitlab-psql python /path/to/your/script.py
   ```

Comment: Does the omnibus-gitlab application require any changes via gitlab-ctl reconfigure after adding a password to postgresql user gitlab-psql?